# Concatenated category listing on product page

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database column as

```
id  |  item  |  category
=========================
1   |  Pen   |  featured
2   | Pencil |  featured,new arrival
3   | eraser |  new arrival
```

On my listing page, I am to list these products out according to their categories i.e, query WHERE clause is dependent on Category Names(featured,new arrival).

Please I need help on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried "anything"?

Comment: did you try something like "LIKE %your_category%"?

Comment: You should really restructure your database and add new two tables: `Category (category_id, category_name)` and `Category_Link (item_id, category_id)`.  You should then be able to do a `JOIN` on the data.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am able to output single category but the concatenated category is the problem here.

Comment: @TimCooper I get your point here. Will see about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set(str, strlist)` function.

> *It returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings.*

```
select * from items 
 where find_in_set( 'new arrival', category ) > 0
```

***Refer to***:

- [**MySQL: FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It really worked perfectly as expected. I'm grateful for this. Much Thanks! I was quick to implement as I knew it's functionality though I didn't give it a try.

Comment: I was waiting for the time to permit me accept your answer. Answers can't be accepted immediately questions are asked. There's a time limit now effective before an answer is accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your table allows duplicated items, you could change it to e.g.

```
id  |  item  |  category
=========================
1   |  Pen   |  featured
2   | Pencil |  featured
3   | Pencil |  new arrival
4   | eraser |  new arrival
```

and you could query the distinct item. e.g.

```
select distinct item from table where category in ('featured','new arrival');
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it returned results not as I expected though. Thanks all the same.